# Ignoring certain file(s) in fish shell history

Tags: fish

I have very recently started using fish shell on my mac. I have a certain (hidden) `.files` which I don't want to appear in the fish command completion (from history), since then they do not remain hidden at all :(.

Is there a way I can make fish ignore all commands involving these files to store to history?

Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start your sensitive commands with a space, that command will not be added to history. Other than hacking the fish sources, I don't know of a mechanism to programmatically filter commands before they're appended to the history.

Comment: that serves the purpose :)